# Azure Pipeline: how to delete a variable inside Azure build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

Currently we are migrating from XAML to Azure Pipelines. To prevent identical buildnumbers we are using a special variable for initialising the build number for the first migrated build definition. After the first build, the variable is obsolete and can be deleted inside the build.
How to do this in Powershell?

Comment: Hi Rainer, what exactly do you mean with "After the first build, the variable is obsolete"?

Comment: Hi friend, would you mind accepting it as answer by clicking on the **check mark** beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in if it's helpful for you. So that we can archive this thread for you and more members can find the useful info easily! Have a nice day~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to do this in Powershell?

It seems that you want to delete/remove unwanted build pipeline variable(Classic build pipeline?) via powershell task, you can use [Definitions-Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) rest api.

```
PUT https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=5.1
```

Here's my working sample to delete the variable via PowerShell task inside the build:

```
$url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/build/definitions/$($env:SYSTEM_DEFINITIONID)?api-version=5.1"

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
}

# Remove the variable you don't like.
$response.variables.PSObject.Properties.Remove('InvalidVariable')

$json = @($response) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}
```

**Step1:** Make sure the job which contains the Powershell task allow scripts to access the OAuth token cause my script uses OAuth token instead of PAT to call rest api. (Click Agent Job Name=>Additional options)

[image]

**Step2:** Find your pipelines page and manage security for the specific build pipeline, **Allow** the `Edit Build Pipeline` for `ProjectName Build Service(OrgName)` user. (It it doesn't work, try allowing permission for `Project Collection Build Service` account)

[image]

[image]

3.Use a normal [Powershell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops) in `Inline script` mode to run my script above. All you need to modify is the variable name. If the Variable's name is `MyVar`, then `$response.variables.PSObject.Properties.Remove('MyVar')`.

Above script gets the Definition first and then remove the unwanted variable, finally update the build pipeline definitions with Definitions-Update rest api.

**Before running the PS task:**

[image]

**After running the PS task:**

[image]

Unwanted variable would be removed.

Comment: Hello Lance Li-MSFT,
thank you very much for detailed description. It is exactly the solution I searched for.
BR,Rainer

Comment: @RainerMuehlberger You're welcome. If it works for you, could you please [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) by clicking the button like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) so that more members can easily find the answer. Thanks!